# Ruby - HTML structure fingerprinting

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I'm looking for a way in ruby to 'fingerprint' html pages based on their structure rather than their content. The idea is to identify certain page types of interest by matching their fingerprint against a reference code.

I found [this](http://tool.motoricerca.info/similarity-analyzer.phtml) (pretty old) tool which seems to do the job well but no clues given as to how the (hex?) code is generated.

I've had a try at using Nokogiri to generate something similar, but not much progress made using that avenue... any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please show the code you wrote so far?

Comment: This isn't easy because a browser treats a page much differently than a parser. The browser renders for display, and elements can move because of CSS and JavaScript so what visually is the same could be very different in the HTML itself and vice-versa. Nokogiri sees the raw HTML so you'd have to tell it how to find the differences that dynamically affect the layout. Possibly using WATIR or a similar tool would help because you could check regions in the rendered page for similarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's a simple problem because there's a lot that affects a document that can occur *after* a parser has seen it vs. a browser rendering the page that has JavaScript and AJAX and the backend sending different markup based on some criteria that's not in the HTML.

That said, here's the basic idea I'd use to generate fingerprints:

```
require 'digest'
require 'nokogiri'

doc1 = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <div class='foo'><p>content</p></div>
    <div class='bar'><p>content</p></div>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

doc2 = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <div class='bar'><p>content</p></div>
    <div class='foo'><p>content</p></div>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

[doc1, doc2].each { |d| d.search('//text()').remove }
Digest::MD5.hexdigest(doc1.to_html) # => "3abe6e365f145452a5c99a38bfdf2339"
Digest::MD5.hexdigest(doc2.to_html) # => "25c4c66fa90c683cc2d3ce1e7e6a461b"
```

Compare that to:

```
require 'digest'
require 'nokogiri'

doc1 = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(<<EOT)
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      // a script
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='foo'><p>content</p></div>
    <div class='bar'><p>content</p></div>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

doc2 = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(<<EOT)
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      // a different script
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='foo'><p>content</p></div>
    <div class='bar'><p>content</p></div>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

[doc1, doc2].each { |d| d.search('//text()').remove }
Digest::MD5.hexdigest(doc1.to_html) # => "13215fefd8efe06268574eaa82f4c765"
Digest::MD5.hexdigest(doc2.to_html) # => "13215fefd8efe06268574eaa82f4c765"
```

where the scripts could be different, resulting in a different page being rendered. Stripping content will strip out the JavaScript making it appear that the pages are the same though they could be drastically different.

The only way I think to do it accurately and reliably is to use something like WATIR, which renders the page using a browser then allows you to look for text on the page.

Comment: so sorry for the delay getting back to you - completely agree that it's hard to make the basic structure bullet proof due to js/ajax etc - but pre-rendering would deal with that. this is a really good start, thanks to both you and to  GSP for the SAX suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

By structure, you simply mean the tags without the attributes and without the text?

You could try the SAX parser available through Nokogiri (or elsewhere). There are two main types of XML parsers: those that build a complete XML structure, and an event-based parser that parses an file in linear time and fires events as it enters and leaves elements. That's how SAX parsers work.

The example code in Nokogiri is a good starting point: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/nokogiri/Nokogiri/HTML/SAX/Parser

The following code builds an array of tag names as they are encountered.

```
# Build a list of tags.
class MyDoc < Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Document
  attr_accessor :tags

  def start_element name, attrs = []
    tags << name
  end

  def end_element name
    # NOOP
  end
end

# Create our parser
parser = Nokogiri::HTML::SAX::Parser.new(MyDoc.new)
parser.tags = []

# Send some XML to the parser
parser.parse(File.open(ARGV[0]))
```

Assuming you started with a document like:

```
<html><head></head><body><p>This is a <strong>test</strong></p></body></html>
```

The output of your parser might be something like

```
parser.tags # => [ 'html', 'head', 'body', 'p', 'strong' ]
```

EDIT: modified the answer to use the HTML SAX parser with HTML error correction rather than the pure XML parser ( http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/SAX/Parser )

Comment: The problem with counting tags is that their location in the document needs to be captured, to get an idea of the page layout. Moving an element in the page would fool code that counts tags but wouldn't fool code that also tracks the element locations. Also, some pages are templates with differing text, so tag count and location won't help, you have to hash the text also. But, then, if there's CSS or JavaScript involved, the pages can look entirely different but have the same HTML layout.

Comment: The SAX parser above will append the tag names to the array in order. It's not just counting tags. Also, I agree with you about the text, but the question explicitly said to exclude content. I took that to mean ignore text.